# mongoose - 'save' method does not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider a mongodb collection running on MongooseJS.

### Sample Code:

```
Person.where('uid').equals(19524121).select('name').exec(function(err, data){
     // Here I can get the data correctly in an array.
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
     data[0].name = "try to save me now"; // Select the first item in the array
     data[0].save(); // Object #<Promise> has no method 'save'.
}
```

### Error - Cant seem to figure out a way to fix this.

> Object #<Promise> has no method 'save';

I am a little confused on why this is happening and I have researched quite a bit and can't seem to find a direct answer for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The result of a `find` is an array of records. You probably meant to loop over those records like this:

```
Person.find({ uid: /19524121/ }).select('name').exec(function(err, data){
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     var myData = new Person(data[i]);
     myData.name = "try to save me now";
     myData.save(); // It works now!
  }
}
```

Also, from [the mongoose homepage](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html), it appears that the function callback prototype is `function(err, data)`, not the other way around, which you corrected above.

Look at this from the homepage:

```
var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
```

If `data[0]` currently has a regular JSON object, we need a line like this to convert to a BSON model object.

```
var myData = new Person(data[0]);
```

Comment: I apologize but when I typed up a sample code, I messed up there and forgot to include the suggestions that you had already stated. Both the ideas that you have stated were already applied as reflected by the updated question.

Comment: I see that. Further research is revealing. Updating the answer now.

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense.

Comment: well, i just need to remove the original Person now otherwise i get conflicting ID's when I try to save the new Person. Just trying to figure that out now. But other that yes!