# Mongoose save() after find, findOne, or findById

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble with using save() after updating a mongoose document. It looks like the type passed from find, findOne, or findById is a Mongoose Document not a model so it lacks the save() function. update() is available, but it skips the middleware, which I need.

Closest I could find is this:
[mongoose - 'save' method does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377495/mongoose-save-method-does-not-exist) but is looks like it still passes a Document to me not a Model instance.

Is it maybe my version? Using the latest in NPM - 3.8.1

```
models.StudySubject.findById(id, function (err, studySubject) {
        if (err)
            return cb(err);

        if (!studySubject)
            return cb({ status: 404, error: 'Study subject not found'});

        var subjectInfo = extractSubjectFields(params);
        delete subjectInfo.study; // prevent study change

        updateObjOneLevel(studySubject, subjectInfo);

        studySubject.save(function (err, studySubject, count) {
            if (err)
                return cb(err);

            if (count !== 1)
                return cb({ status: 500, error: 'Error saving Study Subject' });

            cb(null, studySubject);
        });
    });
```

`extractSubjectFields()` looks at the input `params` for optional update fields like:

```
if (params.study)
        subjectInfo.study = params.study;
```

Stacktrace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'
 at C:\....\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1270:13
```

Schema:

```
var studySubjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        default: function() { return uuid.v4() },
        match: [/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/, "Invalid UUID"]
    },
    study: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Study',
        required: "Study reference is required: `{PATH}` - `{VALUE}`"
    },
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        encrypt: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        encrypt: true
    },
    date_of_birth: {
        type: String,
        encrypt: true
    },
    mrns: [MRNSchema],
    metadata: {
        type: {},
        validation: [function (val) {
            return (typeof val == 'object');
        }, "Metadata field must be a key/value object"]
    },
    enrollments: [{
        type: String,
        match: [/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/, "Invalid Enrollment UUID"],
        ref: 'Enrollment'
    }]
});

var enrollmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        default: function() { return uuid.v4() },
        lowercase: true,
        match: [/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/, "Invalid UUID"]
    },
    study: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Study',
        required: "Study reference is required: `{PATH}` - `{VALUE}`"
    },
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date_of_birth: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mrns: [MRNSchema],
    metadata: {
        type: {},
        validation: [function (val) {
            return (typeof val == 'object');
        }, "Metadata field must be a key/value object"],
    },
    consents: [ConsentSchema],
    subject_study_code: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    unenrolled: {
        type: Date
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: `findById` returns a model instance for me (ctor name is `model`). Could it be that `updateObjOneLevel()` is doing something strange?

Comment: I've tried commenting on that function and just manually modifying a property `studySubject.first_name = 'Barney'` and still gives me an error that save() does not exist, but update() does and document.js is the file in the stacktrace

Comment: Hmm `console.log(studySubject.save);` gives me `{ [Function] numAsyncPres: 0 }`

Comment: The code mentioned in the stack trace is related to what looks like a nested document array. Sounds like you might be mixing subdocuments and document references?

Comment: Added the Schema for the Model and the Model it references in an Array. Is that maybe tripping it up?

Comment: What I think is going on (and I might be wrong) is that your document might be getting converted into a regular object (rather than a document instance).  Try this: `console.log(studySubject.save)` before and after the `updateObjOneLevel(studySubject, subjectInfo)` line.  If you are seeing it disappear after the method gets called then your method is changing it to an object.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what's happening exactly, but my guess is that it's related to the `mrns` array.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica that was my initial guess too but apparently commenting it out didn't fix the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It actually did have to do with the mrns array.

It's fixed by using `subjectInfo.mrns = deepCopy(params.mrns);`

I guess it was pointed to elsewhere in code which for some reason affected adding the object as array as a subdocument array. So creating a deep copy fixed it.

The reason commenting out `updateObjOneLevel()` still affected it was there is a `pre('save` hook on that encrypts the MRN field (it also encrypts first_name, last_name, date_of_birth). Which is probably something I should have mentioned, but didn't think the pre hooks could affect it. The encryption plugin could also be the one causing it, it sometimes encrypts objects that referenced elsewhere, which is why deep copies should be passed.

Thanks everyone!!